# index word in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I have a text file where I want each word in the text file in a dictionary and then print out the index position each time the word is in the text file.
The code I have is only giving me the number of times the word is in the text file. How can I change this?
I have already converted to lowercase.

```
dicti = {}  

for eachword in wordsintxt:
    freq = dicti.get(eachword, None)
    if freq == None:
        dicti[eachword] = 1
    else:
        dicti[eachword] = freq + 1

print(dicti)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want your dictionary to look like,.  If each key is a word, what are the values?  You should definitely be looping over `for index, word in enumerate(wordsintxt):` to track the index as well as the word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to keep the indices themselves, rather than merely count them:

```
for index, eachword in enumerate(wordsintxt):
    freq = dicti.get(eachword, None)
    if freq == None:
        dicti[eachword] = []
    else:
        dicti[eachword].append(index)
```

If you still need the word frequency: that's easy to recover:

```
freq = len(dicti[word])
```

**Update per OP comment**

Without `enumerate`, simply provide that functionality yourself:

```
for index in range(len(wordsintxt)):
    eachword = wordsintxt[i]
```

I'm not sure why you'd want to do that; the operation is idiomatic and common enough that Python developers created `enumerate` for exactly that purpose.

Comment: that is perfect! thank you. Is there a way of doing it without the enumerate function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
wordsintxt = ["hello", "world", "the", "a", "Hello", "my", "name", "is", "the"]
words_data = {}

for i, word in enumerate(wordsintxt):
    word = word.lower()
    words_data[word] = words_data.get(word, {'freq': 0, 'indexes': []})
    words_data[word]['freq'] += 1
    words_data[word]['indexes'].append(i)


for k, v in words_data.items():
    print(k, '\t', v)
```

Which prints:

```
hello    {'freq': 2, 'indexes': [0, 4]}
world    {'freq': 1, 'indexes': [1]}
the      {'freq': 2, 'indexes': [2, 8]}
a        {'freq': 1, 'indexes': [3]}
my       {'freq': 1, 'indexes': [5]}
name     {'freq': 1, 'indexes': [6]}
is       {'freq': 1, 'indexes': [7]}
```

You can avoid checking if the value exists in your dictionary and then performing a custom action by just using `data[key] = data.get(key, STARTING_VALUE)`

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.defaultdict` with `enumerate`, just append all the indexes you retrieve from enumerate

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open('test.txt') as f:
    content = f.read()

words = content.split()
dd = defaultdict(list)

for i, v in enumerate(words):
    dd[v.lower()].append(i)

print(dd)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'i': [0, 6, 35, 54, 57], 'have': [1, 36, 58],... 'lowercase.': [62]})
```